# How do I insert vim commands into register?

Tags: vim

I wanted to insert the an operator, e.g. `i` manually into my macro register. So, if I wanted to insert the `i` operator (insert after the cursor), I do it like this:

`:let @x="\ihello\n"`

When executing the macro `x` multiple times, e.g. with `3@x` I get this result:

```
hello
ihello
ihello
```

Vim recognizes the new line `\n`. but only recognize `\i` once. For the remaining lines vim prints out the command `\i` as a string 'i'.

How do I insert vim commands (`i` for inserting, `<esc>` for escaping, removing, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\i` is not a command. Vim just interprets the string `"\i"` as plain `"i"` (`\i` is not a valid escape sequence). Your code is equivalent to `:let @x = "ihello\n"`.

The problem is that your macro enters insert mode with `i`, but never leaves it, so the next `i` is just inserted literally. This is like executing `ii`: The first `i` starts insert mode, the second `i` is inserted. (You can observe this behavior by doing `@x`: It will insert `hello\n` and leave you in insert mode.)

To fix your macro, you need to put an <kbd>Esc</kbd> character in your string. See `:h expr-string` for a list of available escape sequences. Two possibilities:

- `let @x = "ihello\n\e"`
- `let @x = "ihello\n\<Esc>"`